# protractor check if DOM has changed

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, protractor

I have a bootstrap form users can preview before sharing it to other people to fill it out but in the preview form I want the buttons not to be disabled but just to have no action on them. Pressing them will do nothing at all.

My initial thought was this:

```
var modal = element(by.id('my-modal'));
element(by.id('submit-button')).click();
expect(element(by.id('my-modal'))).toBe(modal);
```

But this fails with the result of the items not being equal.

How do I for the DOM to be the same?

Comment: maybe comparing it's length properties will work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of comparing elements, compare its getText length:

```
var modal = element(by.id('my-modal'));
var m1length;
modal.getText().then(function(text) {
      m1length = text.length;
    });
element(by.id('submit-button')).click();
element(by.id('my-modal')).getText().then(function(text) { 
expect(text.length).toBe(m1length);
});
```

Comment: getText returns a promise so getText().length is undefined while the first one will work. On a second note, comparing the two getText() promises should work since both derive from the same variable

Answer (score 2):

`toBe` does a reference comparison, so your example does not work because you have two instances of `element(by.id('my-modal'))`.

It depends on what you want to compare. If you want to make sure the DOM is identical (down to attributes and structure), you can compare the resulting html:

```
var htmlBefore = element(by.id('my-modal')).getOuterHtml();
element(by.id('submit-button')).click();
expect(element(by.id('my-modal')).getOuterHtml()).toBe(htmlBefore);
```

Or you can compare the text (i.e. `getText()`). It really just depends on what you define as "same".